# Cordova3.9.2 + jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 back button issue in iOS9

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am facing an issue in iOS. I used Cordova3.9.2 + jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 which was working perfect in iOS8 but when I upgraded iPad to iOS9 it's back button is not working.

I tried

> $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled=false

but due to this it was not allowing me to go back by using

> parent.history.back();

so I set it true,

> $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled=true

after that it is navigating back till second screen but not more than that and it goes back to login page which is my first page of screen

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. I am sharing if anyone facing the same issue can follow these below steps to resolve back button issue:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady(){
   $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = true;
   $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use it via link button ,this one works well on both android and ios .

you dont need jquery self

`<a href="#"  onclick="history.back(); return false">BACK</a>`